# Can ping router but can't connect to the internet on Ubuntu Server 20.04.5

Tags: ubuntu, networking

My family and I got new internet recently and every other device works perfectly on it except for my Ubuntu Server, and I can't figure out why. I can ping my router address just fine (192.168.1.254) but I can't ping google.com or 8.8.8.8. I got it to work briefly by messing around with the IP routing table, but it stopped working after a restart.

route -n prints out:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp2s0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp2s0
10.8.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp2s0
192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 enp2s0
```

systemd-resolve --status prints out:

```
 systemd-resolve --status
Global
       LLMNR setting: no
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 3 (tun0)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Link 2 (enp2s0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
DefaultRoute setting: yes
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
  Current DNS Server: 192.168.1.254
         DNS Servers: 192.168.1.70
                      8.8.8.8
                      192.168.1.254
          DNS Domain: attlocal.net
```

I'm at a loss, any advice would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your router is `.254` but the higher priority gateway is `.1`, so your server will try to go through that.

Comment: @zwets thank you for the response! How do I change that then? edit: nevermind, I figured it out. Thank you again, what a simple solution...

Comment: Actually, after a restart it goes back to the previous issue... I'm not sure why.

Comment: Probably because there is something in the setup or a startup script that configures things wrong. You need to find out where and remove the bad gateway definition. (I think recent versions of Ubuntu uses netplan, that I don't know, so I have no idea where this might be).

Answer (score 2):

You have two default gateways on your server at the same time. See these lines:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp2s0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp2s0
```

The first row takes precedence because it has a lower number in the Metric column.

Having two default gateways at the same time is very uncommon, and in the vast majority of cases it is a mistake of setting up a network interface on the server.

Adjust the settings so that the first default gateway disappears. It's probably a remnant of your previous internet connection, which is no longer working.